# to transcend or to be transcended

Tags: gerunds

"In basic terms, transculturalism might be provisionally defined as the transcendence and questioning of cultural delimitations."

What is meant in the text I'm working on is that transculturalism transcends cultural delimitations. To me, the use of "transcendence" here sounds like the cultural limitations are doing the transcending, so to speak, rather than being transcended. I am considering changing "transcendence" to "transcending" (i.e., "the transcending of"). Am I wrong?

(Looking ahead, I see that "transcendence" is used quite a lot in this text, so I want to make sure I'm right before rejecting every instance.)

Comment: I like the idea, but not the hedgy wording. In academia, writers can't suggest 2+2=4. Instead, *In basic terms*, 2+2 *might be provisionally defined as* 4.

Comment: Sure, transcending and questioning something is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Delimitations are transcended by somebody or something, same way as boundaries are crossed. Delimitations don’t transcend themselves.

Comment: So, do you agree with me about "transcendent" vs. "transcending"?

Comment: Okay either way. Because “questioning” is a gerund, it will pair with a noun or another gerund. “Transcending” is probably better stylistically.

Comment: PS. If you go with “transcending and questioning”, the “of” gets dropped.

Comment: I would have thought the "of" getting dropped would depend on the "the" before “transcending and questioning” getting dropped.

Comment: @Elise. Agreed.